# Angular 2 first service call .subscribe() fails with "connection is closed"

Tags: angular

The first one fails while the second one doesn't fails.

```
this.doelplatformService.getAllDoelplatformen()
  .subscribe(
  doelplatformData => this.doelplatformGridOptions.api.setDatasource(doelplatformData));

this.userService.getAllUsers()
  .subscribe(
  userData => this.userGridOptions.api.setRowData(userData));
```

This is the error:

```
{ ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
at C:\Users\myname\Documents\Octopus\Octopus 2.0\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1569:17
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
name: 'ConnectionError',
message: 'Connection is closed.',
code: 'ECONNCLOSED' }
(node:7376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? 
Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

Here is the code with the getAllDoelplatformen() function

```
getAllDoelplatformen() {
return this.http.get('/api/doelplatformen')
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And it points to this api:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var sql = require("mssql");

var dbconfig = {
server: "**********",
user: "**********",
password: "***********",
options: {
    database: "*********"
}
};

// Get all doelplatformen
router.get('/doelplatformen', (req, res) => {
sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    request.query("SELECT [Alg].[DefTarget].[ShortName] Platform, [Alg].[DefTarget].[ID] FROM [Alg].[DefTarget];", function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
        }
    });
    request.query();
});
});
```

Comment: Show us the code of `this.doelplatformService.getAllDoelplatformen()` and any call to open the database, it looks like your connection to the database is not made properly in there.

Comment: I added it today. I had a busy weekend, sorry!

Comment: is it nodejs? if so check if you can reach the REST endpoint through browser

Comment: Yes and yes, I can get all the data in json format in my browser... The functions work, but not when I call them both from the same file...

Comment: I'm also seeing the file as 'Pending' in my chrome dev tools network tab... And after some time it does load the file?

Comment: After 2 minutes it does load the file?